# why isn't my drop down menu displaying as block?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, block

I had to rearrange a few things in my CSS and now my drop down menus don't display as block. The drop down menu is made through jquery, but I know the code is correct. Now it's either and html or a css problem. I'll post the css and if the html is needed let me know, I will add it.

HTML:

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul class="navList">
        <li><a class="navLink" href="">Home</a></li>

        <li id="navLink1"><a class="navLink" href="">Services</a></li>
        <ul class="dropDown" id="dropDown1">
            <li>Pricing</li>
            <li>Examples</li>
            <li>Additional Services</li>
        </ul>

        <li id="navLink2"><a class="navLink" href="">Info</a></li>
        <ul class="dropDown" id="dropDown2">
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Our Portfolio</li>
        </ul>

        <li><a class="navLink" href="">FAQ's</a></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
    #navigation{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.navList li{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px; 
}
.navList li:hover{
    background-color: #3399FF;
}
.navLink{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px white;
}
.dropDown{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(46, 184, 230, .9);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-left: 2px solid lightgray;
    border-right: 2px solid lightgray;
}
.dropDown li{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;

}
.dropDown li:hover{
    background-color: #3399FF;
}
#dropDown1{
        top: 185px;
        left: 272px;
        display: none;
}
#dropDown2{
        top: 185px;
        left: 382px;    
        display: none;
}
```

[here is my jsfiddle if it helps](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd37W/)

Comment: Could you provide a Fiddle?

Comment: anyone got anything yet.

Comment: As block what do you mean? Vertical drop down?

Comment: yes thats exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is displaying. If you mean why it's not displaying vertically, it's because you have float:left and display:inline for all the li:

```
.navList li{
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
***float:left;***
***display: inline;***
padding: 5px;
margin-right: 25px;
font-size: 20px;
border-radius: 15px; 
}
```

All you need to add is:

```
.dropDown li{
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
padding: 5px;
***float:none;***
***display:block;***
}
```

Comment: so what should I add to the dropdown section to counter this.

Comment: you have to set the dropDown li to float:none and have them display:block

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dropdown menus are displaying as block when jQuery toggles them on. Your child li elements within the ul.dropDown elements are not set to display as block.

ALso, you may not be able to hover over the menus because they are outside of the #navLink1 and #navLink2 elements. Placing the dropDown withn the navLink may help this.

```
<li id="navLink1">
  <a class="navLink" href="">Services</a>
  <ul class="dropDown" id="dropDown1">
    <li>Pricing</li>
    <li>Examples</li>
    <li>Additional Services</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I know the problem with the #navLinks, I still have to add to divs. But let me try adding the 2 displays.

Comment: I added display: block; to the class .dropDown, but that did not work. Any other ideas.

Comment: add "display:block;" and "float: none;" to ".dropdown li"

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to align the dropdowns with the navigation item you should put the dropdown inside the containing li element and position it after that. Also, for styles that you only want on the direct children li elements of navlist without affecting other children of children use the ">" symbol.

Here's the CSS:

```
#navigation{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.navList li{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px; 
}
.navList > li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}
.navList li:hover{
    background-color: #3399FF;
}
.navLink{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px white;
}
.dropDown{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(46, 184, 230, .9);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-left: 2px solid lightgray;
    border-right: 2px solid lightgray;
}
.dropDown li{
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}
.dropDown li:hover{
    background-color: #3399FF;
}
```

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/Sd37W/18/